# how to search for retweets based on hashtag in php?

Tags: php, twitter

Also, how can i retrieve the results of the s hashtag search and see who all have retweeted that tweet in php. I have seen the api but did not find much info on hashtag search. did find other normal search but i wanted to search based on hashtag.

Suggestions please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just include the hash when searching for the tag, i.e, `#tagname`

Make sure you also urlencode the search term, otherwise the # will be intepreted as an anchor and not part of the querystring. Example code:

```
<?php
$tag = '#apple';
$url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=' . urlencode($tag);
echo $url;
?>
```

This will output:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23apple
```

Comment: i think you understood me wrong... i am not trying to search in twitter.com website. I am trying to make it automatically work as a script.  Here is a sample code from twitter api... `http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=#apple` This is not working.

But what works in `http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=apple`

Comment: I've updated my answer corresponding to your new information.

Comment: Thanks Emil. How can i show the content of this url on my php webpage. Alos i can see that .atom is retrieving only 20 tweets.. how can i show all of them at one place?

Comment: What i want to do is to show the list of all users, on my webpage, who have used this hashtag in their statues. There is also json version, but i do not understand how to grab the output of this link and show only the user_name user_id and full name on my webpage.

Comment: I don't know how to get more results. It's probably in the API documentation.

Comment: This doesn't really explain how to use php to get tweets based on a hashtag search.

Comment: sequoia, the OP clearly did know how to search with the API already, he just needed help to format the URL for hashtags (since # is a special character in URLs). To actually perform the search, just file_get_contents($url) and parse it as an Atom feed (there are libraries for that).